# Google app engine flexible not load context path of Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I have spring boot application and already deploy on GAE Flexible env.
In my application, I already set my application context path in application.properties file look like:

```
server.context-path=/myapp
```

And it work fine on tomcat and jetty embedded server.

But when I deploy to GAE flex env my application not work with context path that I already set on my application.properties file.
It auto use context path "/" in GAE domain.

Because I'm using dispatch to defined routing on GAE with multi microservice, so I have to define a specify context path for each service.

Anybody can help me in this case?
Thanks.